# What layer or pattern should I use in my Laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, architecture, refactoring, backend

I have an app with about 10 work modes. Each "mode" works with the same API-endpoints, but differs from others in 2-5 columns that it uses and sometimes in logic. I need some kind of layer to leave controller just doing the common job. For example (pseudo code):

Controller:

```
function create($request) {
    DoCommonJob();
    SomeLayer::createByMode($request);
    return response;
}
```

SomeLayer:

```
function createByMode($request) {
    Switch($request->('mode')) {
       ...
    }
}
```

What layer or a pattern can I use in my case?

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail on the solution you currently have and why you're having problems with it?

Comment: @jsheeran actually, right now I have a demo version (not in production) with multiple endpoints and controllers named like api/mode/action, [Mode][Entity]Controller. I tried to make some upgrades and updates and it was very exhausting practice. I need to merge endpoints but if I do it now I'll have almost 1k lines controllers with if(mode == 1) { ...30 lines...} if(mode == 2) { ...30 lines...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I understood that there is no need for complex patterns. I just decided to create custom class Handler (Ex: [Entity]Handler.php) where I will place the custom logic. And methods from [Entity]Controllers will append the code from functions in handlers.